# How can I display data extracted from database in html tag?

Tags: html

I have this php code to fetch data from the database but can't seem to figure out how to do that and i need your help:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM moviesdet";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<a href="./invideo.php?movieID=' . $row["movieId"] . '">' . $row["movieIMG"] . '</a>';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

And this html code is a place where i want to put my extracted data in:

```html
<div class="someMovies"></div><div class="someMoviesHere"></div>
```

What I want is to display some data from database in first div[(someMovies) like 2-3 elements] and other data in second div(someMoviesHere) like 4-5 elements from database.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What if the query returns 50 rows, then what?

Comment: Please show us the solution you came up with.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can copy and paste the following and modify some of the number according to your requirement.

```
<div class="someMovies">
    <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM moviesdet LIMIT 3";//you can change number of limit based on your requirement
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '<a href="./invideo.php?movieID=' . $row["movieId"] . '"> <img height="200px" width="200px" src="'. $row["movieIMG"] . '"></a>';//you can modify height and width of the image to your required one
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
            unset($sql);
        ?>
        </div>
        <div class="someMoviesHere">
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM moviesdet LIMIT 5";//you can change number of limit based on your requirement
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '<a href="./invideo.php?movieID=' . $row["movieId"] . '"> <img height="200px" width="200px" src="'. $row["movieIMG"] . '"></a>';//you can modify height and width of the image to your required one
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
            unset($sql);
        ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain your solution so that others can learn. What does `WHERE RAND()` do?

Comment: @Dharman thanks for asking it will randomly fetch data from the database i thought he doesn't want the same data to be fetched and shown to the user again and again since it's the movie related. i can't believe i just got 3 down vote on the answer that works perfectly i was just trying to do the best thing and this is very demotivating.

Comment: We don't appreciate code that doesn't teach us how to do it. Also your approach to mysqli is quite complicated. You should separate HTML from PHP. Don't give up, you can still improve this answer by explaining your suggestion. Or maybe this question was not the best one to answer. Sometimes the question deserves a downvote and no answers. You really need to evaluate whether this Q&A will help future developers learn new concepts. Remember we are not here to just help OP write code, we want to have a repository of useful information for everyone.

Comment: @Dharman  perhaps you're right you can take a look at most of my previous answers i always try to explain as much as possible and on this one i was kind of in a hurry and just wanted to help that individual. Indeed the answers should be future programmers oriented and some questions do not deserve answer. i wish if i could delete this answer but i guess i don't want this valuable comment of yours be deleted with the answer so i'm going to keep this answer here thanks again.

Comment: As long as this answer doesn't get accepted, then the whole question will be removed by the system in 10 days